# Return week start (Monday) based on current day

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below code returns sunday instead of monday for week start- can someone please help me troubleshoot

```
function myFunction() {
 var curr = new Date();
  
var first = (curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()) ;
  
var Monday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(curr.setDate(first)), "UTC", "YYYY-MM-dd");
  
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
 sh.getRange("F4").setValue(Monday) ;

}
```

Comment: For your reference in your future posts, please do try to search the question first before posting. Try google, then stackoverflow.